# How to resolve could not find sdk microsoft.vclibs version=11.0 error in windows 8 bing maps?

Tags: windows-8

I am getting the could not find sdk microsoft.vclibs version=11.0 error while running the bing maps sample app in windows 8.please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: I've got an email (for one of my apps) from Microsoft which explains that the Bing SDK is not available yet. It will be released in the mid of September.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add a reference to "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package" in the project references?  (Windows -> Extensions)

Comment: i didn't find any of reference with that name in windows--Extensions

Comment: i installed windows 8 release preview.

Answer (score 1):

download the Bing Maps SDK for Windows Store apps from here:  https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/224eb93a-ebc4-46ba-9be7-90ee777ad9e1
that should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add reference to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\platform.winmd' instead of 'Microsoft.VCLibs'

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration manager (Build -> Configuration Manager), check that the active solution platform pulldown menu is not set to "Any", but is instead set to x86, x64 or ARM as applicable.

That fixed the problem for me.